# What will be the DNS name for Virtual Machine instance created in IBM Bluemix?

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud, openstack

I have created a Virtual Machine in Bluemix. I have installed NGINX web server on it. To access the web application that is deployed on NGINX, should I use a public IP address (for e.g. http://123.456.78.9) or is there a domain name associated with the instance (something like http://abcxyz.bluemix.net)?

Answer (score 1):

When you launch any VM in cloud by default they should be not accessible from public internet unless you attach a public ip address to them.

Once you have attached a public ip address to your instance and configured the firewalls to allow incoming connections (http, ssh etc) you can update your DNS server to redirect traffic there.

AWS create a public FQDN at the time of launching the ec2 instances as

ec2-nn-nn-nn-nn-region-compute.com (where nn are ip address bits), not sure any similar thing with bluemix but it is less likely to have abcxyz.bluemix.